# how to sign apk on different computers?

Tags: android, apk

I want to work and upload my application to Google play from 2 different computers. How properly to sign the apk on them? Does it mean that I need to sign on both of them with same keystore file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you have to use same keystore file for that APK file.

For that you need to copy that keystore file in both computers and after that use that keystore file path for your apk file.

Answer (score 1):

You need have to copy you keystore files on both computers! AS simple as that!

Answer (score 1):

just create a keystore and use it to sign your app on different computers

The procedure for creating keystore is :
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/generate-signed-apk-wizard-specify-key-and-keystore.html

I wish you know how to transfer your keystore from one computer to another.